# Connection refused on Ubuntu on Vagrant-Parallels

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I'm trying to `vagrant up` three Ubuntu 20.04-arm64 servers on Mac m1 and getting a loop cycle of errors:

```
==> db: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    db: SSH address: :22
    db: SSH username: vagrant
    db: SSH auth method: private key
    db: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    app2: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    app1: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    db: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    app2: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    app1: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    db: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
```

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # General Vagrant VM configuration.
  config.vm.box = "jeffnoxon/ubuntu-20.04-arm64"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider :parallels do |v|
    v.memory = 256
    v.linked_clone = true
  end

  # Application server 1.
  config.vm.define "app1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app1.test"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.4"
  end

  # Application server 2.
  config.vm.define "app2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app2.test"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.5"
  end

  # Database server.
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "orc-db.test"
    db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.6"
  end
end
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Also experiencing the same issue, and it seems related to the recent update of the box. I assume the creator has assigned the same mac address to each box. When used with parallels this then forces each box to share the same DHCP address which seems to break parallels

The fix is to revert from box version 1.0.1 and use version 1.0.0, until the author fixes the duplicate MAC address issue

For example

```
  config.vm.box = "jeffnoxon/ubuntu-20.04-arm64"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!